# Use hooks for undo/redo admin actions?

Tags: core-modifications

Is it possible to implement a undo/redo by tracing admin actions?

I know its gonna be a heavy task, but is it possible at all? Plugins aside of course, core is enough, though

Comment: Could you be more specific please.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. Once you delete a post or a file you can't "bring them back" just by reversing the admin actions, for that you will need to store the various states of the system and not only the hooks that have been used.